# Java Mysql Database - I want to Hide one row result

Tags: java, mysql

I want to hide one row result from the database with matching entry,
like a column type binary if the entry is 1 hide it but if it's 0 show it.

Comment: Please show your query statement

Comment: Here's my query statement - "String sql = "SELECT * FROM awardees ORDER BY Surname"

Answer (score 0):

your SQL statement should be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM awardees
WHERE binary_col = 0
ORDER BY surname ASC
```

This will return you all the rows that have 0 as value in the binary column.
If you want to add extra conditions you can use logic operators like "AND" "OR" and "NOT" in your where condition. For example I want only awardees that have the surname starting with P, I will do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM awardees
WHERE binary_col = 0
    AND surname LIKE 'P%'
ORDER BY surname ASC
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to table with Name: `isHide`, type: `bit`, default value: '0'.
For how row want to hide set `isHide` with '1'.
In query you can check it in `WHERE` statement.